# Official documentation for seeding in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

Is there any official documentation on seeding in Ruby on Rails?

I've come across third-party documentation in the form of a [Railscast episode on it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data), but I'd also like to know what documentation if any the Rails team has produced.

In the Rails guides post on [ActiveRecord Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data), there's a section saying that you should use seeding, but not an awful lot of information on how to do so, and no links to relevant information. Doing a google search of the API using `seed site:api.rubyonrails.org` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you're having a hard time finding API documentation is because there really isn't that much to it. There is just a rake task `rake db:seed` which will require `db/seeds.rb`.

`rake db:seed` is in turn invoked by other tasks such as `rake db:reset`

The seed files in many projects are just some declarative or imperative code which creates a bunch of model instances. The [gem Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) is pretty handy for these kinds of tasks (creating pseudo-random filler data for the dev. env.).

I have used it sometimes to mirror the production db with `heroku pg:backups`.